# SQLServer 2008 PIVOT on multiple fields issue

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, pivot, unpivot

I am trying to using PIVOT on 3 fields/Columns i.e Site, Value, Date.I am using SQLServer 2008.Please check below my actual table  and desired output table and the pivot query i used

Actual Table:

```
**tblReference**


**ID**            **Refer_code**    **Site**    **Value**   **Date**

  1                 9290             CA            12.5         2014-01-01 20:20:41

  5                 9290             TX            12.6         2014-01-05 18:20:30

  2                 6651             CA            13.5         2014-01-01 21:20:21

  3                 7442             TX            14.5         2014-01-05 19:15:14

  4                 8093             CA            15.5         2014-01-01 19:20:20

  6                 8093             TX            16.5         2014-01-05 20:20:20


**Desired output table:**


**Refer_code**   **Site_1** **Site_2**  **Val_1**  **Val_2**    **StartDate**   **EndDate**

   9290            CA         TX      12.5       12.6   2014-01-01      2014-01-05
                                                                20:20:41    18:20:30

   6651            CA         NULL    13.5       NULL   2014-01-01      NULL
                                                                21:20:21    

   7442            NULL       TX      NULL       14.5   NULL            2014-01-05 
                                                                                19:15:14

   8093            CA         TX      15.5       16.5   2014-01-01      2014-01-05
                                                                19:20:20    20:20:20


 **Query:**

        SELECT Refer_code, [Site_1], [Site_2], [Date_1] AS StartDate, [Date_2] AS EndDate, [Val_1], [Val_2]
        FROM
        (
        SELECT Refer_code, Site, 'Site_'+ cast(row_number() over(partition by Refer_code order by Date) as nvarchar(50)) SiteVal,Date,'Date_'+cast(row_number() over(partition by Refer_code order by Date) as nvarchar(50)) DateVal,Value,'Val_'+cast(row_number() over(partition by Refer_code order by Date) as nvarchar(50)) Val
            FROM tblReference
        ) x
        pivot 
        (
            min(Site)
            for SiteVal in ([Site_1], [Site_2])
        ) p 
        pivot
        (
            min(Date)
            for DateVal in ([Date_1], [Date_2])
        ) s
        pivot
        (
            min(Value)
            for Val in ([Val_1], [Val_2])
        ) t
```

The above query is not returning the result as expected.Please help me on the solution.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to get the desired result.  The easiest way might be to use an aggregate function with a CASE expression but you can also use the PIVOT function.

**Aggregate with CASE:**

I would take the following steps, first create a unique sequence for each `refer_code` using `row_number()`:

```
select refer_code, site, 
  row_number() over(partition by refer_code
                    order by date) seq,
  value,
  date
from tblReference;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2d2e1/8).

Once you have the unique sequence you can easily convert your existing data into multiple columns by applying an aggregate function with a CASE expression:

```
;with cte as
(
  select refer_code, site, 
    row_number() over(partition by refer_code
                      order by date) seq,
    value,
    date
  from tblReference
)
select refer_code,
  max(case when seq = 1 then site end) site1,
  max(case when seq = 2 then site end) site2,
  max(case when seq = 1 then value end) value1,
  max(case when seq = 2 then value end) value2,
  max(case when seq = 1 then date end) startdate,
  max(case when seq = 2 then date end) enddate
from cte
group by refer_code;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2d2e1/11)

**PIVOT:**

If you want to use the PIVOT function and you need to pivot multiple columns I would suggest looking at unpivoting those columns first, then applying the pivot function.  You will need to create the unique sequence which is used for your new column names, then you need to unpivot the `site`, `date` and `value` columns.  Since you are using SQL Server 2008+ you can use `CROSS APPLY` with `VALUEs` to unpivot the multiple columns into multiple rows:

```
;with cte as
(
  select refer_code, site, 
    row_number() over(partition by refer_code
                      order by date) seq,
    value,
    date
  from tblReference
)
select *
from
(
  select refer_code, 
    col = col + cast(seq as varchar(10)),
    val
  from cte
  cross apply
  (
    values
      ('Site', site),
      ('Value', cast(value as varchar(10))),
      ('Date', convert(varchar(10), date, 120))
  ) c (col, val)
) d;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2d2e1/5).  This gets your data into the format of:

```
| REFER_CODE |    COL |        VAL |
|------------|--------|------------|
|       6651 |  Site1 |         CA |
|       6651 | Value1 |      13.50 |
|       6651 |  Date1 | 2014-01-01 |
|       7442 |  Site1 |         TX |
|       7442 | Value1 |      14.50 |
|       7442 |  Date1 | 2014-01-05 |
```

Now you can easily apply the pivot function to get the final result, so the entire code will be:

```
;with cte as
(
  select refer_code, site, 
    row_number() over(partition by refer_code
                      order by date) seq,
    value,
    date
  from tblReference
)
select refer_code, 
  site1, site2, 
  startdate = date1, enddate = date2,
  value1, value2
from
(
  select refer_code, 
    col = col + cast(seq as varchar(10)),
    val
  from cte
  cross apply
  (
    values
      ('Site', site),
      ('Value', cast(value as varchar(10))),
      ('Date', convert(varchar(10), date, 120))
  ) c (col, val)
) d
pivot
(
  max(val)
  for col in (site1, site2, date1, date2,
              value1, value2)
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2d2e1/9). Both will give a result of:

```
| REFER_CODE | SITE1 |  SITE2 |  STARTDATE |    ENDDATE | VALUE1 | VALUE2 |
|------------|-------|--------|------------|------------|--------|--------|
|       6651 |    CA | (null) | 2014-01-01 |     (null) |  13.50 | (null) |
|       7442 |    TX | (null) | 2014-01-05 |     (null) |  14.50 | (null) |
|       8093 |    CA |     TX | 2014-01-01 | 2014-01-05 |  15.50 |  16.50 |
|       9290 |    CA |     TX | 2014-01-01 | 2014-01-05 |  12.50 |  12.60 |
```

Edit:

Based on your comment that you need the columns to be `CA` as `site1`, etc. then the easiest way to get the result would be using an aggregate function with CASe:

```
select refer_code,
  max(case when site = 'CA' then site end) site1,
  max(case when site = 'TX' then site end) site2,
  max(case when site = 'CA' then value end) value1,
  max(case when site = 'TX' then value end) value2,
  max(case when site = 'CA' then date end) startdate,
  max(case when site = 'TX' then date end) endate
from tblReference
group by refer_code;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6a2df/1). This gives a result:

```
| REFER_CODE |  SITE1 |  SITE2 | VALUE1 | VALUE2 |                      STARTDATE |                         ENDATE |
|------------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------------------------------|--------------------------------|
|       6651 |     CA | (null) |   13.5 | (null) | January, 01 2014 21:20:21+0000 |                         (null) |
|       7442 | (null) |     TX | (null) |   14.5 |                         (null) | January, 05 2014 19:15:14+0000 |
|       8093 |     CA |     TX |   15.5 |   16.5 | January, 01 2014 19:20:20+0000 | January, 05 2014 20:20:20+0000 |
|       9290 |     CA |     TX |   12.5 |   12.6 | January, 01 2014 20:20:41+0000 | January, 05 2014 18:20:30+0000 |
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.But i got the idea of using it.I used aggregate and case.I have one query: a)The expected output is not as shown above.If you observe Refer_Code 7442.It is not shown up at CA but shown up at TX.So i should show Site1 =  NULL and Site2 = TX.Similary in the PIVOT case

Comment: @user3311016 So you are saying that CA is always site1 and TX is site2?  Do you have any other sites?  Will you always just have site1/site2, value1/value2?

Comment: Hi, No there is no fixed sites.But always 2  distinct Sites at any given set of records Site1, Site2, Val1, Val2.In that some refer_code are shown up at Site1, Some at Site2, Some at both.Seems to be some other conditional reference required to identify that or will there be any way to get that using lower Date val

Comment: @user3311016 you will need some way to identify what value goes with site1/site2, do you have anything like that?